# How change value in database with SSH

Tags: module, odoo, gantt-chart, odoo-14

I can access to Odoo project only with ssh (VS Code or Cmd)

when I change Field Type "date" to "datetime" I get this error (Show in the picture)

I want to change it with MySQL Server using SSH in table 'ir_model_fields' name = 'date_start' ttype='datetime'

Please any solution for this?

[image]

Comment: You can't edit properties of fields defined through python code (The error in right picture)

Comment: Of course, I did it and nothing happen

Comment: What exactly did you do?

Comment: This wouldn't affect the .py file where the field is declared, meaning it'll go back each time odoo is restarted. Curious how you can access the database but not the files, though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare date like this

```
my_date = fields.Date(string='My Date')
```

Comment: I have this

`date_start = fields.Datetime(string='Start Date')
date = fields.Datetime(string='Expiration Date', index=True, tracking=True)`

Comment: date_start and end_date must be the same type (For example datetime or date)